# Stack Overflow newsletters being quarantined for suspicious inline attachments

Tags: support, newsletter, virus

In the past week I've had two Stack Overflow newsletters quarantined. The exact message is:

> Notification: virus : Suspicious Attachments(inline)".

The newsletters were:

- New performance questions for Nov 1
- Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter - Tuesday, November 4, 2014

Is anyone else having similar issues?

The newsletters are sent to my work address and IT releases the emails without complaint.  I reviewed the two newsletters and didn't find any common questions between the two.